# AngularJS hiding div form another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have one DIV that is have under the ABC controller, and I have another button That is under the XYZ controller when i clicked on the button the DIV should me hide using ng-class ex( ng-class="{ 'hidden': showDetails }")

Please help me on this

Comment: The ng-click solutions below will only work if the div you need to hide is in the same or in a child scope (from the button scope). If not, you could (and should) use a service and $broadcast an event which the div's controller will listen and hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<button ng-click="hideDiv=true">hide the button</button>
<div ng-hide="hideDiv">Div that will be hidden</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-init="hideIt = false"></div>
<button ng-click="hideIt =true">click me</button>
<div ng-if="hideIt">Div to hide</div>
```

or

inorder to use ng-class

```
<div ng-init="hideIt = false"></div>
<button ng-click="hideIt =true">click me</button>
<div ng-class="{'hidden': hideIt}">Div to hide</div>
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

we can use angular `services` or `factory` to share the data between multiple controllers, so u can use `services` or `factory` in your case also,

here is the `service` [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tsurxHaKSrM8yOUDGVhp?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Kalhano need more details on this i can use the function in hidden class i can use only variable like ng-class="{ 'hidden': showDetails }" i need to pass the true/false value to the showDetails

Comment: I mean i should pass the value (true/false) to showDetails

Comment: I am hiding and showing the div as pre the user events there are soo many events(click, seleted, focus and many) all are working fine bcoz of they are in the same controller. But i want make all events should be work with passing value in single variable(showDetails).